# VBA to cut specific range of cells based on another cell

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, copy

Hoping some VBA expert out there can help me!

I need to identify rows of data that contain a duplicate value in column H, and then cut the data from cells N:S of the first duplicate row and paste it on the end of the first row, at the first empty cell

I'll try and explain that better...

Columns A:G can be ignored. Column H contains duplicates of a number. Where duplicates are found, I need to cut the data in column N3:S3 of the first duplicate (row 3,h3 in the example) and append it to the end of the existing columns, as new columns.

The attached Image shows the current state of the data, in rows 1:3 and rows 8:9 show how it should end up looking like.

[image]

I'm hoping someone can interpret this and help me out!!

Thanks

I've managed to get the following VBA to run, by recording a macro that mirrored roughly what i hope to achieve. The main issue is that where I've manually copied rows 1:3, id like the code to recognise the duplicates (grouping them together as such) and then selecting the relevant data:

```
' Macro1 Macro

    Sheets("Report").Select
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("H1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$17").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=RGB(255, _
        199, 206), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    Rows("1:3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet10").Select
    Range("N3:S3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("T2:Y2")
    Range("T2:Y2").Select

    Rows("3:3").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? Also, what happens if the duplicate found exists in the column you want to place it in, or is this fresh each time?

Comment: Your image shows only taking one of the duplicates, the 2nd one, how is this determined, have you considered formulas?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where to start is the honest answer. I'm no whizz on vba for sure. From what I have figured out so far, for any duplicates in column H, whatever data they have in cells N:S needs adding as new columns.

Comment: As for formulas, again, I wasn't sure where to begin with those

Comment: I've managed to get the following code to run, by recording the macro, but of course this is me manually selecting the rows that i'm interested in

Comment: What do you want to do with the duplicate row?

Comment: i'd want to delete the duplicate row, once I've moved the data from cells n3:s3 to the row above into cell t2